# How to Display a p tag if WordPress comment date below April 2014?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I need to display a HTML when the  comment date  below April 2014 . This is my wordpress date code

```
<time datetime="2014-05-26T12:19:33+00:00">May 26, 2014 at 12:19 pm</time>
```

I want to display following HTML

`<p class="comment-rating"> <img src="#"><br>Rating: <strong>5 / 5</strong></p>`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normaly you should show the attemp of what you've tried so far.

Here is one way to do it:

```
$(function () {
    var checkDate = new Date("2014-05-01");
    $.each($("time"), function () {
        var $timeItem = $(this);
        var currentDate = new Date($timeItem.attr("datetime"));
        if (currentDate < checkDate) {
            $timeItem.after('<p class="comment-rating"> <img src="#"><br>Rating: <strong>5 / 5</strong></p>');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/36bg4/2/